# How to use dict in class as switch statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to use dict as a switch statement in python class like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    METHODS_MAP = {}  # I want to place map here

    # some code here
    def caller(self, instructions):
        methods_map = {
            "a": self.a,
            "b": self.b
        }
        for key, value in instructions.items():
            methods_map[key](value)

    def a(self, val):
        print("Called a")

    def b(self, val):
        print("Called b")


a = MyClass()
instr = {"b": 12, "a": 14}
a.caller(instr)
```

Right now it works just fine, but I need to place `methods_map` at the same level as method definitions as static variable as some might say. I tried this:

```py
class MyClass:
    METHODS_MAP = {
        "a": self.a
   }
```

or

```py
class MyClass:
    METHODS_MAP = {
        "a": a
   }
```

But either way, it doesn't know about class methods. How can I make it work my way?

Comment: These are instance methods, not class methods. You could put the dict in the `__init__` method.

Comment: @Wups thanks, looks like a good idea, but still not clean enough

Comment: @AlexanderZh. - why isn't that `clean enough`? You probably need to add more explanation to your question stating what you are try to achieve and/or avoid.

Comment: @Wups at the second thought, there is nothing particularly dirty about putting them in the constructor. My only worry is that it's the same to every instance of that class, so why would I create it every time when I call constructor? It's just looks so much better when created as 'static' variable

Comment: Each `self.a` etc encodes `self` in the method, so it can't be 'static'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them in the constructor like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods_map = {
            "a": self.a,
            "b": self.b
        }

    def caller(self, instructions):
        for key, value in instructions.items():
            self.methods_map[key](value)

    def a(self, val):
        print("Called a")

    def b(self, val):
        print("Called b")


x = MyClass()
instr = {"b": 12, "a": 14}
x.caller(instr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference methods implemented inside a class the following syntax is required:

```
METHODS_MAP = 
{
    'a': MyClass.a,
    'b': MyClass.b
}
```

Because some functions work on class instances and are not `@classmethod`s, we need to change the `caller()` function:

```
from inspect import ismethod

def caller(self, instructions):
    for key, value in instructions.items():
        if METHODS_MAP[key].__self__ is MyClass: # check if function is class method
            METHODS_MAP[key](MyClass, value)
        elif ismethod(METHODS_MAP[key]): # check if method is an instance method
            METHODS_MAP[key](self, value)
        else: # static method
            METHODS_MAP[key](value)
```

If the desired function is not a `@classmethod`, `self` will be passed to it. Else, it will be called as usual

**Important note:** Although this solution seems more complex than initializing the `MEHTODS_MAP` dictionary inside the `__init__()` function, it is far less costly. With this method, the number of instances this class has does not affect the number of times `METHODS_MAP` will be created in memory (there will always be just one).

With the other method suggested here (using `__init__()`), for every instance of `MyClass()` a copy of `METHODS_MAP` will be needlessly created, since it is initialized inside the `__init__()` function

Comment: This is also a nice approach to it. But maybe the OP has just provided an example with `a` and `b` in the question and whatif they are using self?

Comment: @ParthS007 you are totally right methods bodies are just examples and functions might use ```self```

Comment: @ParthS007 now my solution works for both class methods and regular methods